# how does RMySQL read ~/.my.cnf?

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

I noticed that RMySQL allows for a user to specify connection "groups" in `~/.my.cnf`, however I after scanning the [github repo](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL), I cannot see where (or how) this file (or `/etc/.my.cnf`) is ever read/parsed...

Can anyone explain how this is happening? I'd like to mimic this functionality in one of my own packages, so I'm trying to take this as a starting point.

Comment: It's built into the underlying C library so not a good example to work from

Comment: Okay, then I have a silly question: what would it take to integrate that functionality into [RPostgreSQL](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rpostgresql.html)?

Comment: Something similar already exists. See the new RPostgres package

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, RPostgres is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to specify the location of your "CNF" file. In most cases it is stored in the home folder.

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)

a <- "C:/my.cnf"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), default.file=a, group='test_db', user=NULL, 
password=NULL)
```